# Extract list of hashmaps from clojure vector which has a specific value

Tags: java, clojure

I have a Clojure vector containing hashmaps.  These hashmaps are not associated with any key themselves.
But *all* of these hashmaps have a common key — lets say `"ckey"`.  I want to extract the those hashmaps whose `"ckey"` has the value `"test"`.

The data is actually a parsed json. Something like this:-

```
testdata :{
sample1 : "samplevalue1"
sample2 : "samplevalue2"
sample3 : {innersample3 : "innersamplevalue3"}
sample4 : "samplevalue4"
sample5 : [{moresample [] 
           link {innersample5 : "innersamplevalue5"} 
           ckeydata [{ckey:"test" something: somethingValue something2: somethingValue2}]}
         {moresample [] 
           link {innersample5 : "innersamplevalue5"} 
           ckeydata [{ckey:"test1"something: somethingValue something2: somethingValue2}]}
         {moresample [] 
           link {innersample5 : "innersamplevalue5"} 
           ckeydata [ {ckey:"test2" something: somethingValue something2: somethingValue2}]}
         {moresample [] 
           link {innersample5 : "innersamplevalue5"} 
           ckeydata [ {ckey:"test" something: somethingValue something2: somethingValue2}]}]}
```

So in this case I want to extract hashmaps from `sample5` whose `"ckeydata"` key has a vector which contains a hashmap having a `"ckey"` value of `"test"`.

The data in Clojure format:

```
testdata {
    :sample1  "samplevalue1"
    :sample2  "samplevalue2"
    :sample3  {:innersample3  "innersamplevalue3"}
    :sample4  "samplevalue4"
    :sample5  [{:moresample [] 
               :link {innersample5  "innersamplevalue5"} 
               :ckeydata [{:ckey:"test" :something: somethingValue something2 somethingValue2}]}
               {:moresample [] 
                :link {innersample5  "innersamplevalue5"} 
                :ckeydata [{:ckey "test1" :something "somethingValue" :something2 "somethingValue2"}]}
               {:moresample [] 
                :link {:innersample5  "innersamplevalue5"} 
                :ckeydata [ {:ckey "test2" :something "somethingValue" :something2 "somethingValue2"}]}
               {:moresample [] 
                :link {innersample5 : "innersamplevalue5"} 
                :ckeydata [ {:ckey "test" :something  "somethingValue" :something2 "somethingValue2"}]}]}
```

Note:  I don't want to use many filters and keep looping through the code.

Comment: This can easily be done with filter, but please provide the actual Clojure datastructure that you are creating from the json (I have no idea if you are turning keys into keywords or strings, for example).

Comment: Provided clojure code please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
(filter
  (fn [{:keys [ckeydata]}]
    (some (comp #{"test"} :ckey) ckeydata))
  (:sample5 testdata))
```

Which is a rather dense version of:

```
(filter
  (fn [sample-map]
    (some
      (fn [element]
        (= (:ckey element) "test"))
      (:ckeydata sample-map)))
  (:sample5 testdata))
```

---

If `:ckeydata` always only contains one element, consider:

```
(filter
  (comp #{"test"} :ckey first :ckeydata)
  (:sample5 testdata))
```